# Printing from Python 3.6 by lp/lpr not recognised

Tags: python

Trying to output a file to a printer from Python3.6. The code is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["lp", "-d HL-L2360D", "shopping.txt"])
```

**which generates**:

```
lp: The printer or class does not exist.
```

The same command from the console works:

```
>>lp -d HL-L2360D shopping.txt
request id is HL-L2360D-1132 (1 file(s))
```

The printer is in a class:

```
>>lpstat -c laser
members of class laser:
    HL-L2360D
```

Googling the error message provides no clues to solving the problem.
Your suggestions please.
Graeme

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
subprocess.run(["lp", "-d", "HL-L2360D", "shopping.txt"])
```

flags and their values need to be different list items for subprocess calls.

Comment: Never thought of that!

Comment: To split a shell command into arguments for `subprocess.run` do  `import shlex; shlex.split("lp -d HL-L2360D shopping.txt")`